# Cannot convert value of type 'Set<UITouch>.Type' to expected argument type 'Set<UITouch>'

Tags: ios, swift

I have written this function to use some of the functionality of the touchesBegan method in Swift for iOS Development.

However, I am not able to call it as I get an error. See below for code. Thank you!

```
func myTouchesBegan( _ touches: Set<UITouch>, event: UIEvent?) -> Int {    
       super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
       var columnTouched = 0
       if let touch = touches.first {
           let position = touch.location(in: view)
           print(position)
           columnTouched = coOrdinateToColumnValue(pos: position.x, divisorCount: 7)
       }
       return columnTouched
   }
```

Trying to call this function like so:

```
var ct = myTouchesBegan(Set<UITouch>, event: UIEvent)
```

results in an error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Set<UITouch>.Type' to expected argument type 'Set<UITouch>'
```

I cannot see where I'm going wrong. Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: `var ct = myTouchesBegan(Set<UITouch>, event: UIEvent)` That's not how you call methods. `Set<UITouch>` and `UIEvent` are classes, not instances.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it with instances not types

```
var ct = myTouchesBegan(setOfTouches, event: eventObj)
```